# .uasset has disappeared from the development environment

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unreal

I'm having a problem with my development environment. In UE5.3.2, while running a project in development mode in the viewport, my electricity was cut off and my computer turned off. After restarting, my main blueprint disappeared. However, in explorer there is a file in the project directory, but UE does not recognize it. I can’t do anything about it, what should I do? (BP_Player [parent type character]) - main pawn classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the Blueprint in explorer but cannot see it in Unreal, unfortunately that means it is corrupted. Because the asset is a binary file, it is not possible for end users to fix the asset.

Unreal Engine *does* autosave assets and you will find these autosaves under the `<project root>\Saved\Autosaves` folder. If you can't find your asset there, I'm afraid reverting the binary asset using source control is the only way out.